# Can we add a text value on number formula field

Tags: formula-field

I know this question looks absurd.

Here is what i want to do. i have a formula field which is a number datatype. I just want to show the value as 'N/A' if the value if a field rate_type='ABC'.

```
IF( Rate_Type__c == 'ABC', Quantity , 'N/A')
```

This gives out an error

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'IF()'. Expected Number,
>   received Text

Is there a way to do this?

Update:

Is there a way we can keep the formatting of a number in Text formula field?

Comment: Insteaad of 'N/A' you can try -1 for same.

Comment: What does -1 do?

Comment: it will do nothing. It is like saying 'N/A'.  normally we use `< 0` value to show not found

Comment: Answer is no. I suggest instead return type why don't you just use return type text. In this case you can simply return Quantity or 'N/A'

Comment: @Ratan The only problem is that i would loose the formatting

Comment: @Prady how you will loose the formatting ?

Comment: Lets say if the value is 10000 if i have it as number it would be shown as 10,000. If i change to Text it will be just 10000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i have an answer for this

Thanks to the post  https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gpInAAI

```
IF( Rate_Type__c != 'ABC', 'N/A' ,   IF(Quantity < 0, "(", "") & 
IF(ABS(Quantity ) >= 1000000, TEXT(FLOOR(ABS(Quantity ) / 1000000)) & ",", "") &
IF(ABS(Quantity ) >= 1000, RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(ABS(Quantity ) / 1000)), 3) & ",", "") &
RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(ABS(Quantity ))), 3) & "." &
IF(MOD(ABS(Quantity ) , 1) * 100 < 10, "0" & TEXT(ROUND(MOD(ABS(Quantity ) , 1), 2) * 100), TEXT(MIN(ROUND(MOD(ABS(Quantity ) , 1), 2) * 100, 99))) &
IF(Quantity < 0, ")", ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the Number datatype is purely numeric. You could set a Null value or 0 but not a text string to a Number field.

The only other way is to have a formula field returning a text value.

Comment: Could we have the formatting of a number into Text formula field

Comment: Yes, you could calculate a number then use TEXT() to turn it into a text result for display.